# How to clearFocus from TexttFields when scrolling Column on Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, focusmanager

I have a column, that contain few TextFields.
This column is bigger than screen of the device, so it's scrollable.
I want to ClearFocus for TextFields when user scrolles screen.

I came up with such solution: 
Created scroll state and added it to my Column; 
For each of TextField's added callback when they focus get changed and storing this value in parent composable; 
For clearing focus i use this code:

```
            val textFieldsHasFocus = textField1IsFocused || textField2IsFocused
            if (scrollState.isScrollInProgress && textFieldsHasFocus)
                focusManager.clearFocus()
```

I wonder if there is a better solution? Perhaps Compose have something out of the box?